# asp.net mvc 5 How to get id from url and save it in another table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hey I use mvc 5 razor and I'm new to this.

I want to get the project id wat I put in the url 
 e.g. /bug/create/4
(The number 4 stands for the id of the project.)

and save it in the bug table

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="BugID,Title,Description,AssigneeID,Priority,Status,Projects_ProjectID")] Bug bug, int id)
        {
            var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()); 
            // is empty in DB
            ViewBag.getIdFromUrlIsHere =id; 

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                bug.User = currentUser;

                // I get an error here
                bug.Projects = id;


                db.Bugs.Add(bug);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.AssigneeID = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "UserName", bug.AssigneeID);
            return View(bug);
        }
```

Can anyone help me?

The error I get is cannot converto to int if I change the int id in my parameter to string I get the same error

MY BUG TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bugs] (
[BugID]              INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Title]              NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Description]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[AssigneeID]         NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
[Priority]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[Status]             NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[ApplicationUser_Id] NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
[Projects_ProjectID] INT            NULL,
[User_Id]            NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Bugs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BugID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Bugs_dbo.AspNetUsers_ApplicationUser_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([ApplicationUser_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Bugs_dbo.Projects_Projects_ProjectID] FOREIGN KEY ([Projects_ProjectID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Projects] ([ProjectID]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Bugs_dbo.AspNetUsers_AssigneeID] FOREIGN KEY ([AssigneeID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Bugs_dbo.AspNetUsers_User_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([User_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ApplicationUser_Id]
    ON [dbo].[Bugs]([ApplicationUser_Id] ASC);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Projects_ProjectID]
    ON [dbo].[Bugs]([Projects_ProjectID] ASC);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_AssigneeID]
    ON [dbo].[Bugs]([AssigneeID] ASC);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_User_Id]
    ON [dbo].[Bugs]([User_Id] ASC);
```

Comment: I'm guessing Projects is a class and not an int. Are you filling up the correct field? Your database provider can only put int values in int data columns

Comment: make bug.Projects of type string

Comment: How is your Bugs table designed? I'm guessing you have a relationship between the Bug table and the Project table so EF(i'm guessing it's EF) creates a Projects property in your Bugs class. Why would you want to put an id in a related table?

Comment: I cant because the id of project is an int so i I change this I get another error

Comment: @Kristof because when I create a new bug the field project_projectID is always null so I cant my bugs when projectID ==  1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, assuming that the id you pass is the id of a project you could prolly fix it in 2 ways :

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
            bug.User = currentUser;

            //Retrieve the project from the database
            var projectRecord = db.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.ProjectID == id);
            bug.Projects = projectRecord;


            db.Bugs.Add(bug);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Or

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
            bug.User = currentUser;

            //Set the project ID directly(i'm assuming you have a projectID property)
            bug.Projects_ProjectID = id;

            db.Bugs.Add(bug);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```